# Android coordinatorlayout adding extra space at the bottom

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` which has `AppBarLayout`(containing `CollapsingToolbarLayout`), RecyclerView, and beneath that an `ImageView`. The issue which I face is `CoordinatorLayout` is adding some extra space below the `ImageView` which should not be present in the UI.

Below is the code of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/root"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
         android:id="@+id/appBar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

         ......

     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

             <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                 android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/myImage"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="100dp"
                 android:contentDescription="@null"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:src="@drawable/static_image" />
     </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: maybe `fitsSystemWindows` adds padding?

Answer (score 0):

Set this to your `LinearLayout`:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

[image]